# Create image using docker for rust application

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile, rust-cargo

I have created the rust application, i would like to dockerize my application. Below is my Dockerfile code, it is from reference. I am having trouble in creating image, I am getting error as below mention.In my local my-app project folder, I have cargo.toml which does not contain any `package name` its contains only `work-space` below is reference. Please help on this.

> error: failed to read `/home/rust/src/my-app/config/Cargo.toml`

```
FROM ekidd/rust-musl-builder:stable as builder

RUN USER=root cargo new --bin my-app
WORKDIR ./my-app
COPY ./Cargo.lock ./Cargo.lock
COPY ./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.toml
RUN cargo build --release
RUN rm src/*.rs

ADD . ./

RUN rm ./target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/my-app*
RUN cargo build --release


FROM alpine:latest

ARG APP=/usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8000

ENV TZ=Etc/UTC \
    APP_USER=appuser

RUN addgroup -S $APP_USER \
    && adduser -S -g $APP_USER $APP_USER

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache ca-certificates tzdata \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/my-app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/rust-docker-web ${APP}/my-app

RUN chown -R $APP_USER:$APP_USER ${APP}

USER $APP_USER
WORKDIR ${APP}

CMD ["./my-app"]
```

```
cargo.toml
[workspace]

members = [
"abcd",
"efgh"
"ijkl"
]
```

After adding the package name in config.toml, i am facing error

> Caused by:
> no targets specified in the manifest
> either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be present

Answer (score 0):

The `name` and `version` keys are required by Cargo to build your application. Adding those should fix the issue:

```
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0" 

[workspace]
members = [
"abcd",
"efgh"
"ijkl"
]
```

Just a heads up, although the `edition` key is not required, if not specified, cargo will default to compiling your application with Rust 2015 Edition instead of the newer 2018 Edition. You should probably  specify your Rust edition (even if you are using the 2015 Edition), to avoid any confusion:

```
[package]
edition = "2018"
```

Comment: I am facing error after update my config.toml with package name above i have updated code about the error.

Comment: Was the cargo.toml properly copied into a directory that contains a `src/main.rs`?